# What is the equivalent of isset($_POST['name']) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

I have two forms (consisting of checkboxes) on two different PHP pages. I want to use the values submitted from the first form to disable checkboxes in the second form.

page1.php:

```
<form method="POST" action="page2.php">
<input type="checkbox" id="1">
<input type="checkbox" id="2">
<input type="checkbox" id="3">
<input type="checkbox" id="4">
<input type="checkbox" id="5">
<input type="checkbox" id="6">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

page2.php:

```
<form method="POST" action="action.php">
<input type="checkbox" id="1">
<input type="checkbox" id="2">
<input type="checkbox" id="3">
<input type="checkbox" id="4">
<input type="checkbox" id="5">
<input type="checkbox" id="6">
<input type="submit">
</form>

<script>
if(!isset($_POST['2'])){
document.getElementById("4").disabled = true;
}
</script>
```

What should I use instead of this?

```
if(!isset($_POST['2']))
```

I can't use jQuery due to professor limitations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First don't forget that you need name attributes on your checkboxes for PHP. Second, although your ids are valid in HTML5, I'd change them to start with a letter to make them HTML4 compatible.

I print the POST variable using php and assign it to `post` in javascript. Then I check if the checkbox exists in the post variable.

page1.php:

```
<form method="POST" action="page2.php">
<input type="checkbox" id="1" name="box1">
<input type="checkbox" id="2" name="box2">
<input type="checkbox" id="3" name="box3">
<input type="checkbox" id="4" name="box4">
<input type="checkbox" id="5" name="box5">
<input type="checkbox" id="6" name="box6">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

page2.php:

```
<form method="POST" action="action.php">
<input type="checkbox" id="1">
<input type="checkbox" id="2">
<input type="checkbox" id="3">
<input type="checkbox" id="4">
<input type="checkbox" id="5">
<input type="checkbox" id="6">
<input type="submit">
</form>

<script>
var post = <?php echo json_encode($_POST) ?>;
if (!post.box2) document.getElementById("4").disabled = true;

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your checkboxes must have a name:

```
<form method="POST" action="page2.php">
    <input type="checkbox" name="someVar1" id="someVar1" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="someVar2" id="someVar2" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="someVar3" id="someVar3" />
</form>
```

Then inside the script on the second page:

```
<script>
<?php 
if( !isset($_POST['someVar2']) || !$_POST['someVar2'] ){
    echo 'document.getElementById("someVar2").disabled = true;';
}
?>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this. Ugly but works:

```
<script>
if (<?php echo !isset($_POST['2']); ?>) {
    document.getElementById("4").disabled = true;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since JavaScript runs on the client and not the server, it's stateless. So, your JavaScript on `page2.php` has no idea about the values submitted from `page1.php`.

To solve this, you need to use PHP inside your JavaScript on `page2.php` like this:

```
<script>
if (<?php echo !isset($_POST['a']) ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>) {
    document.getElementById("4").disabled = true;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A PHP solution to your question:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="2" name="2" />

<!-- ... -->

<!-- rather than disable if it isn't set, only show if it is set -->
<?php if (isset($_POST['2'])) { ?>
  <input type="checkbox" id="4" name="4" />
<?php } ?>
```

**Note that your inputs must have a name.**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php if (!isset($_POST['2'])) { ?>
<script>
document.getElementById("4").disabled = true;
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Can try something like below

```
var post_val = <?= json_encode($_POST) ?>;
if (typeof post_val['2'] == 'undefined') {
   document.getElementById("4").disabled = true;
 }
```

Comment: How did this get two upvotes when it has **absolutely** nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score -2):

Jquery can make it simple:
for input/textarea/, you can use ***$('#id_for_input_or_textarea').val() != ''*** to check whether it's empty. for radio/checkbox, you can use ***$(':radio:checked').length != 0 /$(':checkbox:checked').length != 0*** to check whether a group of them are checked. or ***$('#some_radio').prop('checked')*** to check if a radio/checkbox is checked.

Comment: Jquery is a little unnecessary don't you think?

Comment: Hey Isaac,jquery is just a tool, anything jquery does can be done without that. pure javascript would be **document.getElementById("nn").value** or **document.getElementById("check1").checked**